Which test is appropriate to test the significance of odds ratios?
I'm new to statistics, and I'm wonderig if there is a best test to use in this situation. I have some odds ratios of age buckets and chance of getting cancer, and I want to test if the odds ratio of each age bucket is significant. I know that there are chi-square and fisher exact tests, but those seem to test the counts. Is there a test that can be used directly on odds ratios?

Do you want to test if each age bucket significant?  Significantly different from what?  What would be the null in this case?

sorry for the confusion; testing them all against one another. Like ages 0-9 vs ages 10-20, 0-29 vs 20-30 and so on

Do you have standard errors to go along with those odds ratios?
